# Can I capture a video without requiring extra permissions?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

I'm trying to record a video using the [MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE) Intent action.

This starts the Camera activity and I can capture a video. The problem is that I don't have the permissions to read the returned `file://` uri:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    String uriStr = intent.getData().toString();
    /**
    * uriString contains file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20160511_142405.mp4
    */
    try {
        getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData()).close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

I would expect the Camera application to grant me temporary permissions as described in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Intents. But it fails with a permission error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20160511_142806.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Is there a way to get the video without the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission ?

Comment: You actually want `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, instead. It implicitly includes `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Actually, just `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is needed by my app. The camera app needs `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` but it has it already.

Comment: `Can I record a video` So, you want to **save it**. Therefore, you actually need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: No I don't. Only the Camera app needs to save it. This camera app is most likely to be shipped with the system and have the appropriate permissions. My app only needs to read the result.

Comment: Then your question title is misleading. For me, to `record` means you want to `save` (= write) something

Comment: Feel free to edit the title

Comment: I changed `record` to `capture`. So it could be more an unwritten thing - like  an in-memory BLOB.

Answer (score 3):

> I would expect the Camera application to grant me temporary permissions

That is not possible with a `file:` `Uri`. That is only possible with a `content:` `Uri`.

> Is there a way to not request the video without the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission ?

Add a `FileProvider` to your app. Then, use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on your `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` `Intent`, supplying a `content:` `Uri` from your `FileProvider`. Include the appropriate flags on the `Intent` to grant write access to whatever app handles your `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` `Intent`. Then — assuming the camera app was well-written — the video will be written to a file on your app's internal storage (or wherever you configure `FileProvider` to serve from), and you will not need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Note, though, that you do need the `CAMERA` permission, at least on Android 6.0+, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23+.

Comment: That looked very promising but I cannot get it to work on my Nexus5X + marshmallow. I pass `content://com.company.video/uploads/1463007061740` in `EXTRA_OUTPUT` and I get `CAM_StateReviewVid: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Can't access /uploads/1463007061740` from the camera App with the preview being black. I think I'll just stick to asking the external storage permissions for now... Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: @mbonnin: That will need to get fixed soon. [`file:` `Uri` values stop working on Android N](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html), once you have `targetSdkVersion` set high enough.

Comment: Damn! Thanks for the details. That being said, I'm not the one creating `file:` uri, the google camera app is. I would be very happy to get a `content:` uri with temp permissions attached except that this is not what's happening now...

Comment: @mbonnin: "That being said, I'm not the one creating file: uri, the google camera app is" -- ah, yes, I was thinking of you switching `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to be a `file:` `Uri`.

Comment: Yep. For now, I just don't use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` at all. If the returned uri is `content://` then everything is good and I get the temporary permissions. If the returned uri is `file://`, I trigger the permission dialog. It's a bit cumbersome but if everyone is moving to `content://` then hopefully people won't see the permission dialog very often. Finger crossed...

Comment: `Note, though, that you do need the CAMERA permission`: just to make it perfectly clear. If you capture images\video through an external app ONLY, you still have to have the `CAMERA` permission declaration in your manifest. right?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov: No, you do not. You need the `CAMERA` permission if you are using the camera APIs (e.g., `android.hardware.Camera`) in your own process, directly or via a library (e.g., Fotoapparat). See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#manifest). However, *if* you request the `CAMERA` permission, *and* the user has not approved it via runtime permissions, *then* you're screwed. So, don't ask for it, if you are not using the camera APIs in your own process.

Comment: It seems to be not correct anymore. I'm testing on API 27 emulator with stock Camera API. 1. When I don't include `CAMERA` permission in `Manifest`, `onActivityResult()` always returns `RESULT_CANCELED`. 2. When I include `CAMERA` permission, but it's not granted in the app settings, app will crash with `SecurityException: Permission Denial` when trying to start `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`. 3. When `CAMERA` permission is in `Manifest` and granted, everything works correctly. BUT everything works without the `CAMERA` permission on older APIs, for instance, on API 23.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov: I can't explain that. I just tested `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` on a Nexus 5X, running Android 8.1, and I do not need the `CAMERA` permission in the manifest for it to work.

Comment: I've figured it out. The issue was that my app created a folder for images on `Application.onCreate()` which obviously failed since at the first run it didn't have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission just after start (user hadn't confirmed the request yet). The frustrating thing is that stock Camera and/or `FileProvider` didn't report a thing to screen or Logcat in the situation when there is an error writing an image to file.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov: Whether any given camera app logs anything is up to the developers of that app, and it would show up in that app's entries in LogCat, not yours. However, I would have expected `FileProvider` to crash and log something on your side, when the camera app asked to open an `OutputStream` on the `Uri`.